# Understanding R convolution code with sapply()

Tags: r, convolution, sapply

I am trying to break apart the R code in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/41263/67822):

```
x <- c(0.17,0.46,0.62,0.08,0.40,0.76,0.03,0.47,0.53,0.32,0.21,0.85,0.31,0.38,0.69)


convolve.binomial <- function(p) {
  # p is a vector of probabilities of Bernoulli distributions.
  # The convolution of these distributions is returned as a vector
  # `z` where z[i] is the probability of i-1, i=1, 2, ..., length(p)+1.
  n <- length(p) + 1
  z <- c(1, rep(0, n-1))
  sapply(p, function(q) {z <<- (1 - q) * z + q * (c(0, z[-n])); q})
  z
}
convolve.binomial(x)
 [1] 5.826141e-05 1.068804e-03 8.233357e-03 3.565983e-02 9.775029e-02
 [6] 1.804516e-01 2.323855e-01 2.127628e-01 1.394564e-01 6.519699e-02
[11] 2.141555e-02 4.799630e-03 6.979119e-04 6.038947e-05 2.647052e-06
[16] 4.091095e-08
```

I tried `debugging` in RStudio, but it still opaque.

The issue is with the line:  `sapply(p, function(q) {z <<- (1 - q) * z + q * (c(0, z[-n])); q})`.

I guess that within the context of the call `convolve.binomial(x)` `p = q = x`. At least I get identical results if I pull the lines outside the function and run `sapply(x, function(x) {z <<- (1 - x) * z + x * (c(0, z[-n])); x})`
:

```
x <- c(0.17,0.46,0.62,0.08,0.40,0.76,0.03,0.47,0.53,0.32,0.21,0.85,0.31,0.38,0.69)
n <- length(x) + 1
z <- c(1, rep(0, n-1))
#  [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
sapply(x, function(x) {z <<- (1 - x) * z + x * (c(0, z[-n])); x})
z # Is extracted by calling it and contains the correct result
```

---

My questions are:

1. What is the purpose of the `;q}` ending within `sapply()`?
2. How does it relate to the `<<-` symbol, meant to make `z` accessible outside of the "implicit" loop that is `sapply()`?

---

Below you can see my problem "hacking" this line of code:

```
(x_complem = 1 - x)
sapply(x, function(x) {z <<- x_complem * z + x * (c(0, z[-n])); x})
z # Returns 16 values and warnings

z_offset = c(0, z[-n])
#  [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
sapply(x, function(x) {z <<- (1 - x) * z + x * z_offset; x})
z # Returns different values.
```

Comment: without a `return` statement, r will return the result of the last eval.  It looks like utilitiy of the function therefore is 3-fold.  To declare `z` in global scope, to calculate `z`, and then to return the input `q`.  `q` as a return value could be just to assist debugging or perhaps to pass it to another function.

Comment: The `z` variable is functioning as both a collection store for intermediate results and a shift operator that focuses attention on the next location of that x variable.

Comment: @42- Could you spell out what operations would take place on a simpler case, say, `x <- c(2,3`, `convolve.binomial(x)`, and I'll be happy to accept the answer. I understand the general principle of convolutions, but I am having problems reconciling it with this `sapply()` function.

Comment: I'll post what I think is a more informative approach to debugging/understnding what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the intermediate values of z as the function proceeds then insert either a `cat` or a `print` command in the code below:

```
sapply(x, function(x) {z <<- (1 - x) * z + x * (c(0, z[-n])); cat(z,"\n"); x})
#--------
0.83 0.17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0.4482 0.4736 0.0782 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0.170316 0.457852 0.323348 0.048484 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0.1566907 0.4348491 0.3341083 0.07047312 0.00387872 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0.09401443 0.3235858 0.3744046 0.1759272 0.03051648 0.001551488 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0.02256346 0.1491116 0.3357823 0.3267701 0.1410286 0.02356488 0.001179131 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
snipped rest of output
```

I think this makes it clearer that what is happening is that each intermediate step represents a set of probabilities for a series of events. Each row sums to 1.0 and represents the probabilities of individual count survivals when there might be a smaller number of binomial parameters. The final result displays the probabilities of particular sums of counts after the full sequence has been assembled.

Another interesting feature is that this result is invariant under random re-ordering of the probabilities in x (as it should be for the original question). Examine the intermediate results from

```
plot(x)
lines(seq(length(z)), z)
z2 <- convolve.binomial(sample(x) )
lines(seq(length(z)), z2, col="red" )
z3 <- convolve.binomial(sample(x) )
lines(seq(length(z)), z3, col="blue" )
```

Answer (score 1):

1. What is the purpose of the `;q}` ending within `sapply()`?

The function within `sapply` return `q`, but actually it's not needed. The following function will work just the same.

```
convolve.binomial <- function(p) {
  n <- length(p) + 1
  z <- c(1, rep(0, n-1))
  sapply(p, function(q) {z <<- (1 - q) * z + q * (c(0, z[-n]))})
  z
}
```

2. How does it relate to the `<<-` symbol, meant to make `z` accessible outside of the "implicit" loop that is `sapply()`?

In R, if you search up the documentation for the `<<-` operator using `?'<<-'` it says that

> The operators `<<-` and `>>-` are normally only used in function, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable to be assigned. If such as variable is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment.

In the function `convolve.binomial` the value `z` is defined local to the function. So `z <<-` actually redefines `z` in the `convolve.binomial` function.

So to summarize, the `z <<-` in the `sapply` call changes the `z` variable already defined in `convolve.binomial` and we eventually return this `z`. The `;q}` ending is not needed within `sapply()`.

Comment: Can you spell out the first couple of steps in the inner workings of this call?